How to create and apply GPO's to individual users or groups on local machine
How can GPO's be created on a non-domain machine?
How can they be applied to individual users or groups.
Is there a Group Policy Management Console? (I find only GPEDIT.MSC)
I am talking about Windows 10 Pro 22H2 and Windows 11

You have many ways to achieve GPO creation from a computer out of the domain.
(In order, best practice solution first and not really recommended last one)

Use Admin Center
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/use/get-started?tabs=add-one

Use RSAT tool with command line to switch user to a domain user with rights to create GPO. (Add the Windows feature; it's an optional feature. You can use powershell to add these features or use the control panel)
runas /netonly /user Domain\Username "mmc gpmc.msc"

Use Remote Desktop to log in to a server from the domain.


After that, you can link your GPO to a specific Organizational Unit (if you can respect the tree) or simply adjust rights (allow user/group to process the GPO) in the delegation tab of the GPO or use WMI Filter.

Thanks
Our machines are all in workgroups.
(3-8 machines each workgroup), hundreds of workgroups ("sites").
So I guess 2 and 3 are out of question.
Is 1 still relevant?
B.t.w I just found secpol.msc which seems to be useable for solving the issues, at least partly

Oh, I misunderstood (I mean only your machine is out of the domain, not that you don't own any Active Directory or a domain).
GPO is part of domain functionalities.
So, with a workgroup, you can only apply Local Policies. (LGPO)
If you want to remotly manage your PCS :
And yes, you can manage PCs with Admin Center. (But Local Policy isn't included in fonctionnalities of Admin Center, but at last you can run powershell script on target machine)
Another way to do it is to enable remote PowerShell on every machine and apply the local policy through PowerShell.

Take a look to :
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80043-apply-local-group-policy-specific-user-windows-10-a.html
And keep in mind the Local Group Policy is stored to : C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers
If you want to script the process you need to pay attention to the SID of local user.
